# Личные сообщения

Tags: mysql

Как организовать у себя на сайте обмен личными сообщениями между пользователями.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В MySQL таблице присваивать одному столбцу "id от кого", второму "id кому".
При запросе пользователем MySQL сделать ограничения

```
Where IdTo = 'id'
```

**Дополнено.**

Допустим У нас есть таблица 'MyTable'
'ID', 'FromID', 'ToID', 'Message' - поля таблицы

P.S.: Таблицу я думаю произвольно можно заполнить самому.

Я - пользователь вашего сайта. Мой id = 569163357.

```
$MyID = '596163357';
```

Чтобы посмотреть все сообщения которые мне присылали:

```
$conn = mysql_connect($SQL_Server, $SQL_Login, $SQL_Pass) or die ("Connection failed!");
mysql_select_db ($SQL_DataBase, $conn) or die("DATABase not found");

$query = "SELECT * FROM `MyTable` WHERE ( ToID = $MyID )";
$result = mysql_query($query, $conn);
```

Чтобы посмотреть все сообщения которые мне присылал пользователь 560969357:

```
$FromUser = '560969357';
$conn = mysql_connect($SQL_Server, $SQL_Login, $SQL_Pass) or die ("Connection failed!");
mysql_select_db ($SQL_DataBase, $conn) or die("DATABase not found");

$query = "SELECT * FROM `MyTable` WHERE ( ToID = $MyID , FromID = $FromUser )";
$result = mysql_query($query, $conn);
```

Comment: Если конечно вам понадобится дополнительная помощь, могу привести пример и код запроса... Обращайтесь.  
Но я думаю по моему обьяснению можно сделать и самостоятельно.

Comment: Если вас не затруднит,приведите мне пожалуйста пример,буду вам весьма благодарен.Заранее спасибо!!!

Comment: Спасибо БОЛЬШОЕ брат!!! Теперь многое прояснилось.побольше бы таких отзывчивых людей.Еще раз благодарен !!!

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв) Всегда рад помочь